# create an excel sheet and insert data from database

Tags: jsp

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
"); response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
"attachment;filename=\"j.xls\"  ");


//int ch=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); String
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"; Connection con =
DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa","sql1423#3"); Statement stmt =
con.createStatement();

HSSFWorkbook hwb=new HSSFWorkbook(); HSSFSheet sheet = 
hwb.createSheet("new sheet"); HSSFSheet sheet1 =  hwb.createSheet("new
sheet1");

HSSFRow rowhead=   sheet.createRow((short)0);

String select[] = request.getParameterValues("id");  if (select != null && select.length != 0) {

    for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++)     {   //out.println(select[i]);
        int ch=Integer.parseInt(select[i]);




        switch(ch)                  {
            case 1 :            rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("INDEX_FLG");            ResultSet
rs=stmt.executeQuery("select INDEX_FLG from FFIX");

              while(rs.next())
              {

                  rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("INDEX_FLG"));
                 //out.println(rs.getString("INDEX_FLG")); 


              }

              rs.close();
                 break;

         case 2 : 

            rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("SYMBOL");           ResultSet rsS=stmt.executeQuery("select SYMBOL from FFIX");;

          while(rsS.next())
          {
              rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rsS.getString("SYMBOL"));
           } 

              rsS.close();
                break;

         case 3 : 
            rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("SERIES");
            ResultSet rsSE=stmt.executeQuery("select SERIES from FFIX");
            while(rsSE.next())          {
                rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rsSE.getString("SERIES"));           
            }
         rsSE.close();
         break;
        }
    }
```

Hi this is my jsp code,i am retriving the value from html page and checks that checkbox values in switch cases.i am trying to create an excel sheet using jsp and inserting records from database into that excel. but when i execute the above code it gives output as white blank excel file..even excel sheet is also not displaying
what should i do now
plz help me
PLZ
Thanx 
Kajal

Answer (score 0):

Do you write the HSSFWorkbook to the outputswstream of the response?

```
hwb.write(response.getOutputStream())
```

Comment: ya i have written in each while of switch case but it prints only one record.....do you have any idea abt this?

Comment: ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select INDEX_FLG from FFIX");
rowhead.createCell((short) i).setCellValue("INDEX_FLG");
     while(rs.next())
     {rowhead.createCell((short) i).setCellValue(rs.getString("INDEX_FLG"));
      hwb.write(response.getOutputStream());
    
      }
   i have written like this.......but it prints only one record in excel sheet

Comment: You should write the workbook only once to the response (that is `hwb.write(response.getOutputStream())`). You should do this at the end of the method, when you have finished processing the resultset and updating the workbook.

Comment: Thank you,but i have changed my code and now it is working fine

Comment: That is great. I get you're new, so you may not aware that this thread is not only about you. You see, if you ask help from SO, you should give something back to the community. So I kindly ask you to post the working version of your code as an additional answer to this question. Otherwise, this whole post would be completely useless to others who may stumble on it. Thanx